# Unable to calibrate Samsung Galaxy Book Touchscreen with Xinput

Tags: drivers, xorg, samsung, touchscreen, xinput

I am having some trouble with my touchscreen on my Samsung Galaxy Book - it is detected by Ubuntu but the Axis is inverted.  I have tried calibrating with xinput and xinput_calibrator and then tried inverting the axes with different coordinates (0,1; 0,0) with "Evdev Axis Inversion" but it doesn't seem like Evdev works with my touchscreen.  I really do not know how to proceed and would appreciate any help.  I have included some more information below:

```
$ xinput_calibrator
Calibrating standard Xorg driver "STMD1234:00 06CB:1058"
        current calibration values: min_x=0, max_x=65535 and min_y=0, max_y=65535
        If these values are estimated wrong, either supply it manually with the --precalib option, or run the 'get_precalib.sh' script to automatically get it (through HAL).
        --> Making the calibration permanent <--
  copy the snippet below into '/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/99-calibration.conf' (/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/ in some distro's)
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier      "calibration"
        MatchProduct    "STMD1234:00 06CB:1058"
        Option  "MinX"  "65359"
        Option  "MaxX"  "-267"
        Option  "MinY"  "63845"
        Option  "MaxY"  "-666"
        Option  "SwapXY"        "0" # unless it was already set to 1
        Option  "InvertX"       "0"  # unless it was already set
        Option  "InvertY"       "0"  # unless it was already set
EndSection
```

I input the final section into a 99-calibration.conf file but didn't see any effect.  Also tried changing the zeros to ones in the SwapXY in this file but did not see any effect.

```
$ xinput --list-props 12
Device 'STMD1234:00 06CB:1058':
        Device Enabled (137):   1
        Coordinate Transformation Matrix (139): 0.000000, -1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
        libinput Calibration Matrix (309):      1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
        libinput Calibration Matrix Default (310):      1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
        libinput Send Events Modes Available (257):     1, 0
        libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (258):        0, 0
        libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (259):        0, 0
        Device Node (260):      "/dev/input/event7"
        Device Product ID (261):        1739, 4184
```

Xorg.0.log:

```
[     9.312] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[     9.317] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
        Using a default monitor configuration.
```

[Removed because of space limitations]

```
[     9.483] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     9.483]    compiled for 1.19.3, module version = 2.3.4
[     9.483]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[     9.483]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
[     9.483] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
[     9.483] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[     9.483] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
[     9.495] (II) modeset(0): using drv /dev/dri/card0
[     9.495] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
[     9.495] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[     9.495] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[     9.495] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[     9.495] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     9.495]    compiled for 1.19.3, module version = 0.0.2
[     9.495]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
[     9.495] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for vesa
[     9.495] (II) modeset(0): Creating default Display subsection in Screen section
        "Default Screen Section" for depth/fbbpp 24/32
[     9.495] (==) modeset(0): Depth 24, (==) framebuffer bpp 32
[     9.495] (==) modeset(0): RGB weight 888
[     9.495] (==) modeset(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[     9.495] (II) Loading sub module "glamoregl"
[     9.495] (II) LoadModule: "glamoregl"
[     9.495] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libglamoregl.so
[     9.568] (II) Module glamoregl: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     9.568]    compiled for 1.19.3, module version = 1.0.0
[     9.568]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[     9.568] (II) glamor: OpenGL accelerated X.org driver based.
[    10.057] (II) glamor: EGL version 1.4 (DRI2):
[    10.105] (II) modeset(0): glamor initialized
[    10.106] (II) modeset(0): Output eDP-1 has no monitor section
[    10.108] (II) modeset(0): Output DP-1 has no monitor section
[    10.109] (II) modeset(0): EDID for output eDP-1
[    10.109] (II) modeset(0): Printing probed modes for output eDP-1
[    10.109] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1280x1920"x60.0  181.56  1280 1340 1364 1441  1920 1935 1937 2100 -hsync -vsync (126.0 kHz P)
[    10.109] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1920x1200"x60.0  154.00  1920 1968 2000 2080  1200 1203 1209 1235 +hsync -vsync (74.0 kHz d)
[    10.109] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x59.9  138.50  1920 1968 2000 2080  1080 1083 1088 1111 +hsync -vsync (66.6 kHz d)
[    10.109] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1600x1200"x60.0  162.00  1600 1664 1856 2160  1200 1201 1204 1250 +hsync +vsync (75.0 kHz d)
[    10.109] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1680x1050"x60.0  146.25  1680 1784 1960 2240  1050 1053 1059 1089 -hsync +vsync (65.3 kHz d)
[    10.109] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1680x1050"x59.9  119.00  1680 1728 1760 1840  1050 1053 1059 1080 +hsync -vsync (64.7 kHz d)
[    10.109] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1600x1024"x60.2  103.12  1600 1600 1656 1664  1024 1024 1029 1030 +hsync +vsync (62.0 kHz d)
[    10.109] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1400x1050"x60.0  122.00  1400 1488 1640 1880  1050 1052 1064 1082 +hsync +vsync (64.9 kHz d)
[    10.109] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x60.0  108.00  1280 1328 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (64.0 kHz d)
[    10.109] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1440x900"x59.9  106.50  1440 1520 1672 1904  900 903 909 934 -hsync +vsync (55.9 kHz d)
[    10.109] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1280x960"x60.0  108.00  1280 1376 1488 1800  960 961 964 1000 +hsync +vsync (60.0 kHz d)
[    10.109] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1360x768"x59.8   84.75  1360 1432 1568 1776  768 771 781 798 -hsync +vsync (47.7 kHz d)
[    10.109] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1360x768"x60.0   72.00  1360 1408 1440 1520  768 771 781 790 +hsync -vsync (47.4 kHz d)
[    10.109] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1152x864"x60.0   81.62  1152 1216 1336 1520  864 865 868 895 -hsync +vsync (53.7 kHz d)
[    10.109] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1024x768"x120.1  133.47  1024 1100 1212 1400  768 768 770 794 doublescan -hsync +vsync (95.3 kHz d)
[    10.109] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1024x768"x60.0   65.00  1024 1048 1184 1344  768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync (48.4 kHz d)
[    10.109] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "960x720"x120.0  117.00  960 1024 1128 1300  720 720 722 750 doublescan -hsync +vsync (90.0 kHz d)
[    10.109] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "928x696"x120.1  109.15  928 976 1088 1264  696 696 698 719 doublescan -hsync +vsync (86.4 kHz d)
[    10.109] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "896x672"x120.0  102.40  896 960 1060 1224  672 672 674 697 doublescan -hsync +vsync (83.7 kHz d)
[    10.109] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "960x600"x120.0   77.00  960 984 1000 1040  600 601 604 617 doublescan +hsync -vsync (74.0 kHz d)
[    10.109] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "960x540"x120.0   69.25  960 984 1000 1040  540 541 544 555 doublescan +hsync -vsync (66.6 kHz d)
[    10.109] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "800x600"x120.0   81.00  800 832 928 1080  600 600 602 625 doublescan +hsync +vsync (75.0 kHz d)
[    10.109] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "800x600"x60.3   40.00  800 840 968 1056  600 601 605 628 +hsync +vsync (37.9 kHz d)
[    10.109] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "800x600"x56.2   36.00  800 824 896 1024  600 601 603 625 +hsync +vsync (35.2 kHz d)
[    10.109] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "840x525"x120.0   73.12  840 892 980 1120  525 526 529 544 doublescan -hsync +vsync (65.3 kHz d)
[    10.109] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "840x525"x119.8   59.50  840 864 880 920  525 526 529 540 doublescan +hsync -vsync (64.7 kHz d)
[    10.109] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "800x512"x120.3   51.56  800 800 828 832  512 512 514 515 doublescan +hsync +vsync (62.0 kHz d)
[    10.109] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "700x525"x120.0   61.00  700 744 820 940  525 526 532 541 doublescan +hsync +vsync (64.9 kHz d)
[    10.109] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "640x512"x120.0   54.00  640 664 720 844  512 512 514 533 doublescan +hsync +vsync (64.0 kHz d)
[    10.109] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "720x450"x119.8   53.25  720 760 836 952  450 451 454 467 doublescan -hsync +vsync (55.9 kHz d)
[    10.109] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "640x480"x120.0   54.00  640 688 744 900  480 480 482 500 doublescan +hsync +vsync (60.0 kHz d)
[    10.109] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "640x480"x59.9   25.18  640 656 752 800  480 490 492 525 -hsync -vsync (31.5 kHz d)
[    10.109] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "680x384"x119.6   42.38  680 716 784 888  384 385 390 399 doublescan -hsync +vsync (47.7 kHz d)
[    10.109] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "680x384"x119.9   36.00  680 704 720 760  384 385 390 395 doublescan +hsync -vsync (47.4 kHz d)
[    10.109] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "576x432"x120.1   40.81  576 608 668 760  432 432 434 447 doublescan -hsync +vsync (53.7 kHz d)
[    10.109] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "512x384"x120.0   32.50  512 524 592 672  384 385 388 403 doublescan -hsync -vsync (48.4 kHz d)
[    10.109] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "400x300"x120.6   20.00  400 420 484 528  300 300 302 314 doublescan +hsync +vsync (37.9 kHz d)
[    10.109] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "400x300"x112.7   18.00  400 412 448 512  300 300 301 312 doublescan +hsync +vsync (35.2 kHz d)
[    10.109] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "320x240"x120.1   12.59  320 328 376 400  240 245 246 262 doublescan -hsync -vsync (31.5 kHz d)
[    10.111] (II) modeset(0): EDID for output DP-1
[    10.111] (II) modeset(0): Output eDP-1 connected
[    10.111] (II) modeset(0): Output DP-1 disconnected
[    10.111] (II) modeset(0): Using exact sizes for initial modes
[    10.111] (II) modeset(0): Output eDP-1 using initial mode 1280x1920 +0+0
[    10.111] (==) modeset(0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
[    10.111] (==) modeset(0): DPI set to (96, 96)
[    10.111] (II) Loading sub module "fb"
[    10.111] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
[    10.111] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
[    10.111] (II) Module fb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    10.111]    compiled for 1.19.3, module version = 1.0.0
[    10.111]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[    10.111] (II) UnloadModule: "fbdev"
[    10.111] (II) Unloading fbdev
[    10.111] (II) UnloadSubModule: "fbdevhw"
[    10.111] (II) Unloading fbdevhw
[    10.112] (II) UnloadModule: "vesa"
[    10.112] (II) Unloading vesa
[    10.112] (==) Depth 24 pixmap format is 32 bpp
[    10.260] (==) modeset(0): Backing store enabled
[    10.260] (==) modeset(0): Silken mouse enabled
[    10.265] (II) modeset(0): RandR 1.2 enabled, ignore the following RandR disabled message.
[    10.270] (==) modeset(0): DPMS enabled
[    10.270] (II) modeset(0): [DRI2] Setup complete
[    10.270] (II) modeset(0): [DRI2]   DRI driver: i965
[    10.270] (II) modeset(0): [DRI2]   VDPAU driver: i965
[    10.270] (--) RandR disabled
[    10.276] (II) SELinux: Disabled on system
[    10.282] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer
[    10.282] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_ARB_create_context
[    10.282] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_ARB_create_context_profile
[    10.282] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_EXT_create_context_es{,2}_profile
[    10.282] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_INTEL_swap_event
[    10.282] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_SGI_swap_control
[    10.282] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB
[    10.282] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float
[    10.282] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_EXT_fbconfig_packed_float
[    10.282] (II) AIGLX: GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap backed by buffer objects
[    10.282] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_ARB_create_context_robustness
[    10.282] (II) AIGLX: Loaded and initialized i965
[    10.282] (II) GLX: Initialized DRI2 GL provider for screen 0
[    10.293] (II) modeset(0): Damage tracking initialized
[    10.293] (II) modeset(0): Setting screen physical size to 338 x 508
[    10.423] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Video Bus (/dev/input/event2)
[    10.423] (**) Video Bus: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[    10.423] (II) LoadModule: "libinput"
[    10.423] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/libinput_drv.so
[    10.459] (II) Module libinput: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    10.459]    compiled for 1.19.3, module version = 0.25.0
[    10.459]    Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
[    10.459]    ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 24.1
[    10.459] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Video Bus'
[    10.459] (**) Video Bus: always reports core events
[    10.459] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event2"
[    10.459] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[    10.459] (II) input device 'Video Bus', /dev/input/event2 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    10.459] (II) input device 'Video Bus', /dev/input/event2 is a keyboard
[    10.472] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input2/event2"
[    10.472] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Video Bus" (type: KEYBOARD, id 6)
[    10.472] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    10.472] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[    10.472] (II) input device 'Video Bus', /dev/input/event2 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    10.472] (II) input device 'Video Bus', /dev/input/event2 is a keyboard
[    10.472] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Lid Switch (/dev/input/event0)
[    10.472] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    10.472] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    10.473] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HID 04e8:a00a Touchpad (/dev/input/event6)
[    10.473] (**) HID 04e8:a00a Touchpad: Applying InputClass "libinput touchpad catchall"
[    10.473] (**) HID 04e8:a00a Touchpad: Applying InputClass "touchpad catchall"
[    10.473] (**) HID 04e8:a00a Touchpad: Applying InputClass "Default clickpad buttons"
[    10.473] (II) LoadModule: "synaptics"
[    10.473] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/synaptics_drv.so
[    10.473] (II) Module synaptics: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    10.473]    compiled for 1.19.3, module version = 1.9.0
[    10.473]    Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
[    10.473]    ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 24.1
[    10.473] (II) Using input driver 'synaptics' for 'HID 04e8:a00a Touchpad'
[    10.473] (**) HID 04e8:a00a Touchpad: always reports core events
[    10.473] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event6"
[    10.624] (II) synaptics: HID 04e8:a00a Touchpad: found clickpad property
[    10.624] (--) synaptics: HID 04e8:a00a Touchpad: x-axis range 0 - 1015 (res 12)
[    10.624] (--) synaptics: HID 04e8:a00a Touchpad: y-axis range 0 - 473 (res 12)
[    10.624] (II) synaptics: HID 04e8:a00a Touchpad: device does not report pressure, will use touch data.
[    10.624] (II) synaptics: HID 04e8:a00a Touchpad: device does not report finger width.
[    10.624] (--) synaptics: HID 04e8:a00a Touchpad: buttons: left double triple
[    10.624] (--) synaptics: HID 04e8:a00a Touchpad: Vendor 0x4e8 Product 0xa00a
[    10.624] (--) synaptics: HID 04e8:a00a Touchpad: invalid pressure range.  defaulting to 0 - 255
[    10.624] (--) synaptics: HID 04e8:a00a Touchpad: invalid finger width range.  defaulting to 0 - 15
[    10.624] (**) Option "SoftButtonAreas" "50% 0 82% 0 0 0 0 0"
[    10.624] (--) synaptics: HID 04e8:a00a Touchpad: touchpad found
[    10.624] (**) HID 04e8:a00a Touchpad: always reports core events
[    10.656] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5/1-5:1.0/0003:04E8:A00A.0001/input/input7/event6"
[    10.656] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "HID 04e8:a00a Touchpad" (type: TOUCHPAD, id 7)
[    10.656] (**) synaptics: HID 04e8:a00a Touchpad: (accel) MinSpeed is now constant deceleration 2.5
[    10.656] (**) synaptics: HID 04e8:a00a Touchpad: (accel) MaxSpeed is now 1.75
[    10.656] (**) synaptics: HID 04e8:a00a Touchpad: (accel) AccelFactor is now 0.179
[    10.656] (**) HID 04e8:a00a Touchpad: (accel) keeping acceleration scheme 1
[    10.656] (**) HID 04e8:a00a Touchpad: (accel) acceleration profile 1
[    10.656] (**) HID 04e8:a00a Touchpad: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[    10.656] (**) HID 04e8:a00a Touchpad: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[    10.716] (--) synaptics: HID 04e8:a00a Touchpad: touchpad found
[    10.716] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HID 04e8:a00a Touchpad (/dev/input/mouse0)
[    10.716] (**) HID 04e8:a00a Touchpad: Ignoring device from InputClass "touchpad ignore duplicates"
[    10.716] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HID 04e8:a00a (/dev/input/event3)
[    10.716] (**) HID 04e8:a00a: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[    10.716] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'HID 04e8:a00a'
[    10.716] (**) HID 04e8:a00a: always reports core events
[    10.716] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event3"
[    10.716] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[    10.717] (II) input device 'HID 04e8:a00a', /dev/input/event3 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    10.717] (II) input device 'HID 04e8:a00a', /dev/input/event3 is a keyboard
[    10.732] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5/1-5:1.1/0003:04E8:A00A.0002/input/input3/event3"
[    10.732] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "HID 04e8:a00a" (type: KEYBOARD, id 8)
[    10.732] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    10.732] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[    10.732] (II) input device 'HID 04e8:a00a', /dev/input/event3 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    10.732] (II) input device 'HID 04e8:a00a', /dev/input/event3 is a keyboard
[    10.732] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HID 04e8:a00a (/dev/input/event4)
[    10.732] (**) HID 04e8:a00a: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[    10.732] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'HID 04e8:a00a'
[    10.732] (**) HID 04e8:a00a: always reports core events
[    10.732] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event4"
[    10.732] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[    10.733] (II) input device 'HID 04e8:a00a', /dev/input/event4 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    10.733] (II) input device 'HID 04e8:a00a', /dev/input/event4 is a keyboard
[    10.756] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5/1-5:1.2/0003:04E8:A00A.0003/input/input4/event4"
[    10.756] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "HID 04e8:a00a" (type: KEYBOARD, id 9)
[    10.756] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    10.756] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[    10.756] (II) input device 'HID 04e8:a00a', /dev/input/event4 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    10.756] (II) input device 'HID 04e8:a00a', /dev/input/event4 is a keyboard
[    10.756] (II) config/udev: Adding input device WCOM0028:00 2D1F:000C (/dev/input/event8)
[    10.756] (**) WCOM0028:00 2D1F:000C: Applying InputClass "libinput pointer catchall"
[    10.756] (**) WCOM0028:00 2D1F:000C: Applying InputClass "libinput tablet catchall"
[    10.756] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'WCOM0028:00 2D1F:000C'
[    10.756] (**) WCOM0028:00 2D1F:000C: always reports core events
[    10.756] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event8"
[    10.756] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[    10.864] (II) input device 'WCOM0028:00 2D1F:000C', /dev/input/event8 is tagged by udev as: Mouse Tablet
[    10.877] (II) WCOM0028:00 2D1F:000C: tablet unknown to libwacom
[    10.877] (II) input device 'WCOM0028:00 2D1F:000C', /dev/input/event8 is a tablet
[    10.928] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.1/i2c_designware.3/i2c-8/i2c-WCOM0028:00/0018:2D1F:000C.0005/input/input17/event8"
[    10.928] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "WCOM0028:00 2D1F:000C" (type: TABLET, id 10)
[    10.929] (II) input device 'WCOM0028:00 2D1F:000C', /dev/input/event8 is tagged by udev as: Mouse Tablet
[    10.933] (II) WCOM0028:00 2D1F:000C: tablet unknown to libwacom
[    10.933] (II) input device 'WCOM0028:00 2D1F:000C', /dev/input/event8 is a tablet
[    10.934] (II) config/udev: Adding input device WCOM0028:00 2D1F:000C (/dev/input/mouse2)
[    10.934] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    10.934] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    10.934] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Intel Virtual Button driver (/dev/input/event5)
[    10.934] (**) Intel Virtual Button driver: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[    10.934] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Intel Virtual Button driver'
[    10.934] (**) Intel Virtual Button driver: always reports core events
[    10.934] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event5"
[    10.934] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[    10.934] (II) input device 'Intel Virtual Button driver', /dev/input/event5 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    10.934] (II) input device 'Intel Virtual Button driver', /dev/input/event5 is a keyboard
[    10.960] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.0/PNP0C09:00/INT33D6:00/input/input5/event5"
[    10.960] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Intel Virtual Button driver" (type: KEYBOARD, id 11)
[    10.960] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    10.960] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[    10.960] (II) input device 'Intel Virtual Button driver', /dev/input/event5 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    10.960] (II) input device 'Intel Virtual Button driver', /dev/input/event5 is a keyboard
[    10.960] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Mic (/dev/input/event9)
[    10.960] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    10.960] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    10.960] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3 (/dev/input/event10)
[    10.960] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    10.960] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    10.960] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=7 (/dev/input/event11)
[    10.961] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    10.961] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    10.961] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=8 (/dev/input/event12)
[    10.961] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    10.961] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    10.961] (II) config/udev: Adding input device STMD1234:00 06CB:1058 (/dev/input/event7)
[    10.961] (**) STMD1234:00 06CB:1058: Applying InputClass "libinput touchscreen catchall"
[    10.961] (**) STMD1234:00 06CB:1058: Applying InputClass "calibration"
[    10.961] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'STMD1234:00 06CB:1058'
[    10.961] (**) STMD1234:00 06CB:1058: always reports core events
[    10.961] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event7"
[    10.961] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[    10.963] (II) input device 'STMD1234:00 06CB:1058', /dev/input/event7 is tagged by udev as: Touchscreen
[    10.963] (II) input device 'STMD1234:00 06CB:1058', /dev/input/event7 is a touch device
[    10.992] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/INT3446:00/i2c_designware.0/i2c-5/i2c-STMD1234:00/0018:06CB:1058.0004/input/input12/event7"
[    10.992] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "STMD1234:00 06CB:1058" (type: TOUCHSCREEN, id 12)
[    10.992] (**) Option "AccelerationScheme" "none"
[    10.992] (**) STMD1234:00 06CB:1058: (accel) selected scheme none/0
[    10.992] (**) STMD1234:00 06CB:1058: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[    10.992] (**) STMD1234:00 06CB:1058: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[    10.994] (II) input device 'STMD1234:00 06CB:1058', /dev/input/event7 is tagged by udev as: Touchscreen
[    10.994] (II) input device 'STMD1234:00 06CB:1058', /dev/input/event7 is a touch device
[    10.994] (II) config/udev: Adding input device STMD1234:00 06CB:1058 (/dev/input/mouse1)
[    10.994] (**) STMD1234:00 06CB:1058: Applying InputClass "calibration"
[    10.994] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    10.994] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    10.994] (II) config/udev: Adding input device AT Translated Set 2 keyboard (/dev/input/event1)
[    10.994] (**) AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[    10.994] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'AT Translated Set 2 keyboard'
[    10.994] (**) AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: always reports core events
[    10.994] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event1"
[    10.994] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[    10.994] (II) input device 'AT Translated Set 2 keyboard', /dev/input/event1 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    10.994] (II) input device 'AT Translated Set 2 keyboard', /dev/input/event1 is a keyboard
[    11.008] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input1/event1"
[    11.008] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "AT Translated Set 2 keyboard" (type: KEYBOARD, id 13)
[    11.008] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    11.008] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[    11.008] (II) input device 'AT Translated Set 2 keyboard', /dev/input/event1 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    11.008] (II) input device 'AT Translated Set 2 keyboard', /dev/input/event1 is a keyboard
[    18.638] (II) modeset(0): Allocate new frame buffer 1920x1280 stride
[   993.389] (II) libinput: WCOM0028:00 2D1F:000C: needs a virtual subdevice
[   993.389] (**) WCOM0028:00 2D1F:000C Pen (0): Applying InputClass "libinput pointer catchall"
[   993.389] (**) WCOM0028:00 2D1F:000C Pen (0): Applying InputClass "libinput tablet catchall"
[   993.389] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'WCOM0028:00 2D1F:000C Pen (0)'
[   993.389] (**) WCOM0028:00 2D1F:000C Pen (0): always reports core events
[   993.390] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event8"
[   993.390] (**) Option "_source" "_driver/libinput"
[   993.390] (II) libinput: WCOM0028:00 2D1F:000C Pen (0): is a virtual subdevice
[   993.390] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.1/i2c_designware.3/i2c-8/i2c-WCOM0028:00/0018:2D1F:000C.0005/input/input17/event8"
[   993.390] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "WCOM0028:00 2D1F:000C Pen (0)" (type: STYLUS, id 14)
[   993.390] (**) Option "AccelerationScheme" "none"
[   993.390] (**) WCOM0028:00 2D1F:000C Pen (0): (accel) selected scheme none/0
[   993.390] (**) WCOM0028:00 2D1F:000C Pen (0): (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[   993.390] (**) WCOM0028:00 2D1F:000C Pen (0): (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
```

Comment: Hello, Can Ubuntu install on Samsung Galaxy Book? Windows 10 performance is worst on this tablet.

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the Coordinate Transformation Matrix property like this:

```
xinput set-prop "STMD1234:00 06CB:1058" "Coordinate Transformation Matrix" 0 1 0 -1 0 1 0 0 1
```